# How to run Jboss over a network?

Tags: java, jboss, ip

I'm using Jboss 4.0.4GA in Windows 10 and I want to run it over a network in port 19443. As described in docs, to achieve this, I need to run the following command: `run.bat -b 0.0.0.0`. After running this, in the host computer I can access normally, but when I access from another computer in the same network, doesn't load anything.

Running `netstat -an` shows `TCP    0.0.0.0:19443          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`.

Any ideas?

Comment: [How to Block or Open a Port in Windows Firewall](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/block-open-port-windows-8-firewall)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks for the suggestion, but even with port opened, I can't access from another PC.

Comment: Check that there isn't a firewall on the client machine. Check that the ip address you're attempting to connect to is correct. Beyond that, no. I can't think of anything else.